# Adding a Bluetooth Peripheral to an STM32

Tags: stm32, bluetooth-low-energy, soc

I'm making a device that is powered by an STM32F072C8Tx.

I want to add a bluetooth peripheral to this that can connect to the computer as a HID and transmit keypresses.

I've considered swapping the STM32 for an nRF52840, as this has all the capabilities that I'd need on a single chip. However, the footprint is somewhat insane, and I'd have to sacrifice access to about half of the GPIO if I got it fabbed by JLPCB. So that's a no-go for me.

So, I figure that I can use a peripheral device to handle the bluetooth transmission and send the keypresses to that over SPI or I2C from my STM32. I've come across the [CC2541](https://www.ti.com/product/CC2541/part-details/CC2541F256RHAR) which looks promising as a bluetooth SOC.

However, looking at this, the CC2541 needs entirely custom firmware, and it's not as simple as send it packets, it transmits them. Which isn't necessarily a problem, but does raise a couple of questions:

1. Does the CC2541 require the use of a proprietary tool-chain or are there open-source alternatives?
2. Is this a sensible approach or am I massively overcomplicating it?
3. Are there any rough equivalents to the nRF52840 that have footprints that don't require microvias or blind vias?
4. Is there a simpler way to do this with a dumb bluetooth peripheral I can just throw packets at and it will transmit and return them?

Comment: If you ask those questions and you are going to design a commercial device I advise you to contract someone who has the experience and knowledge to do the task.

Comment: I have no intentions of it being a commercial device...

Comment: I recommend the new esp32-s3. I just designed a esp32-s3-mini board for testing; it has a lot more available gpio’s (the esp32 also had, but not all were usable). It has wifi/bt included and a lot of users.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for a personal project, why don't you use the HC05 or HC06 to transmit and receive data ? You can hook it up to your UART peripheral and it becomes transparent. Meaning, it would look like you're communicating through UART.

[image]

Credits : Martyn Currey

There are many tutorials on this with Stm32 boards and Arduinos such as this one : http://www.martyncurrey.com/connecting-2-arduinos-by-bluetooth-using-a-hc-05-and-a-hc-06-easy-method-using-cmode/

And I have personally used the HC05 to send real time data to my PC using an STM32 Mcu.

Comment: I've not heard of the HC-06, will have a look... Thanks